# Python Multiprocessing + MPI though Slurm

Tags: python, mpi, python-multiprocessing, slurm, mpi4py

I have a python program that scales at two levels using MPI and Multiprocessing within Python. I need to have one rank on every node which further spawns subprocesses and orchestrates their behaviour.

Assuming I have 8 cores on each of these nodes, my SLURM jobscript looks like this:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8
```

But my results still look rather suspicious like the subprocesses are still using only one CPU. I know that MPI processes by default bind to one core. Is the --cpus-per-task=8 enough to compensate for that or are there some options I'm missing for this?

Comment: What if you `mpirun hostname` ? Do you see 2 tasks, one on each node ? Now what if you `mpirun grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status` ? Is each task running on one or 8 cores ? Btw, what is your MPI library and version ?